# Cannot set property id of undefined

Tags: typescript

```
selectedUsers = [];

for (let index = 0; index <  this.updateOffer.user_ids.length; index++) {
    const element = this.updateOffer.user_ids[index];
    this.selectedUsers[index]['id'] = element;
    console.log(this.selectedUsers)
}
```

I get error in the console

> Cannot set property id of undefined

Expected output

```
 this.selectedUsers = [{ id: 4 }, { id: 6 }];
```

Comment: There is no object in `this.selectedUsers[index]` for which you could set `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is empty, therefore any index you try will be undefined

```
selectedUsers[0]
===> undefined
```

I think what you are trying to do:

```
for (let index = 0; index <  this.updateOffer.user_ids.length; index++) {
    const element = this.updateOffer.user_ids[index];
    this.selectedUsers.push({id: element });
    console.log(this.selectedUsers)
}
```